XCode "No Account for Team", running someone else's code on physical device?
I've been given someone else's codebase in Flutter, and I can't run it on my physical ios device because their Xcode development team is different:

I tried this suggestion, but I don't have an option to set a team on the General tab. I also tried deleting and redownloading provision profiles to no avail.
Will I need to ask the previous owner of the codebase to add me as a collaborator in their Apple developer dashboard or something like that? Can this issue be resolved on my end, or will I have to ask the other owner of this codebase to do something on their end?

You just switch the Team pop-up to yourself or a team you are on. You cannot run code on a physical iOS device without being on some team.

@matt of course, but then I'd get the "Failed Registering Bundle Identifier" error because that bundle identifier is being used by the other team. I can't change the bundle identifier because this app is already being used on TestFlight

Then yes, they have to put you on their team. Or if they no longer work on this code they can transfer the app to you. But what you're saying does not square with my experience. I run open source apps on my device using my team even though they are in the App Store and registered to a different company. I can't put them in the App Store under my name, obviously, but I don't want to. I just want to play with the code.

That sounds fun, more fun than fighting with Xcode configuration. Other devs still work on it, and they were able to add me to their team. Thanks for the suggestion

In my case I had to reach out to the other developer to add me to his development team in App Store Connect. Once that went through, I went to Xcode > Settings > Accounts, clicked the new developer team that I was just added to, pressed Download Manual Profiles, then selected it in the Team dropdown. After that everything works fine.

Where did the other developer had to add you to his dev-team?
